# How to run 1 GB .sql file on SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, sql-server-2012, sqlcmd

I plan to use RedGate Compare 10 to compare two databases and create a third one with desired differences. The two backups I have are 1GB each, and I set up a SQL Server 2012 to use RedGate on the local server. The problem is I have to create the databases using the .sql files, but the files are so large that when I executed the script:

1. Through the import wizard: ran out of memory.
2. Through the sqlcmd: ran out of memory.

   ```
   sqlcmd -S [servername] -d [databasename] -i [scriptfilename] -a 32767 -x
   ```

The machine I am using is running on Windows 7, 4GB RAM, 2.3 GHz i5. Is there a way to create the two 1GB databases I want in the server, or the only option is using better machine and how much of an upgrade will I require?

Comment: is it possible to split the files into chunks? something like you insert 2000 lines and put a Go statement, then another 2k lines... of course you could use some tools to do the splits job...

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, or if even splitting will be supported by the memory. Because such a big file cannot be open by a text edit.

Comment: about splitting large files, some reference (but i never tried it...): http://superuser.com/questions/94083/how-to-split-large-file-on-windows

Comment: Thanks, but that might add more problem if the SQL code breaks at the wrong place in splitting. And I would still want to know the answers to my questions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CSV Splitter - it's free software and it lets you decide how many rows to add to each file.

Comment: Not what I am looking for. :( I already have the huge sql file made, and there is no changing it. If I split it at some random line number (since I can't open it) it will definitely screw up the command.